# how to view the marquee text in full screen in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, marquee

I have a class for [MarqueetextField](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/408/comment-page-1#comment-14497),it Displays the 6 letter only and also it doesn't  display full Screen

for Example if i type"Beautiful Girl".It Displays five letter only (Beaut)

It moves five letters only.How to move full screen?.Anybody help me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either set `width` or the `autoSize` property on your `TextField`.

```
myText.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
```